# Removing one point of the Möbius strip

Tags: general-topology

What space do we get (up to homotopy equivalence) if we take the Möbius strip and remove a point?

Comment: You get a circle with a line connecting two of its points. That space is obtained by taking the boundary $\partial I^2$ of a square and identifying $(0,y)$ with $(1,1-y)$.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the Moebius strip as the (appropriate) quotient of a square identifying its sides.

Remove the center of the square. Then we can retract the interior of the square minus its center to the contour of the square. After identification we get two loops attached at a point.

Comment: That picture is a projective plane